# Do I have to touch someone's shoulder to say 'there there'?

Tags: phrase-usage, expressions

To say 'there, there' do I have to touch someone's shoulder?
If so can I say it while touching another part of the body?

For example:

> **There, there,** don't cry. Everything will be OK.

Or can I say it without doing it?

Comment: No. The word ***there*** in this context is essentially ***phatic*** (it doesn't really "mean" anything, and you *certainly* shouldn't assume it's got anything to do with the "location" sense of the word in other contexts).

Comment: Have a look at [What does “there, there” actually mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50090/what-does-there-there-actually-mean) and [Where did “There, there” (in consoling) come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33238/where-did-there-there-in-consoling-come-from) as asked on ELU.

Answer (score 2):

"There-there", as noted in a comment, does not really mean anything.  It is an expression used when comforting something.  Just like saying "Bless you" when someone sneezes does not really mean a blessing.

"There there" is well [described](http://www.word-detective.com/092906B.html#therethere) as a "comforting verbal gesture".  It goes naturally with other comforting gestures, such as gentle contact on a non-threatening part of the body, such as a shoulder. Depending on your relationship "gentle non-threatening contact" could be a hug, a pat on the head or a back-rub.  But you can say "there there" without touching.

I'm not sure how common it actually is. The context is rather unusual, it would normally be a parent comforting a child (and so not a context that English Language Learners are likely to be in, though it might be used for a piece of fiction) In this context you would probably have picked up the child and be making lots of hushing and soothing sounds, but I suspect this is common across languages and cultures.  I suspect it is rather unlikely used adult-to-adult, but this kind of language is poorly recorded in corpora of written English.